# Tomcat 5.0 serving static resources with UTF-8 encoded filenames

Tags: tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding

I try to setup a Tomcat-Server Version 5.0.30-27.35 on a Suse Linux Enterprise Server 11.2. There is a whole bunch of static resources that should be served through this tomcat too. (Upgrading the tomcat-Server is not an option due to admin-limitations on that systems.) The Problem is, that some files have filenames with special characters and these files are not delivered by the Tomcat-Server - e.g. I get a HTTP 404 error, when accessing http://myserver/qm-iso/aä.html in the browser (wget, FF, IE, Chrome). (file /qm-iso/aä.html exists)

My Setup:

- The Linux-Server is set to UTF-8.
- The Tomcat is started with JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8.
- The Tomcat-HTTP-Connector ist set to URIEncoding="UTF-8" `<connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">` in the server.xml.
- The Default-Servlet has an init-param fileEncoding in the web.xml

  `<init-param><param-name>fileEncoding</param-name><param-value>UTF-8</param-value></init-param>`

I've set up a Test-JSP, that prints out`<%= System.getProperty("file.encoding") %>` and `<%= (new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream())).getEncoding() %>` - both show UTF-8.

I've set the tomcat-log-level to debug and read these logging-statements, when accessing the URL http://myserver/qm-iso/aä.html

```
Attributes
javax.servlet.forward.request_uri : /qm-iso/a%C3%A4.html
javax.servlet.forward.context_path : 
javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path : /qm-iso/aÃ¤.html
javax.servlet.forward.path_info : /error.html
javax.servlet.error.request_uri : /qm-iso/a%C3%A4.html
javax.servlet.error.servlet_name : default
javax.servlet.error.status_code : 404
javax.servlet.error.message : /qm-iso/a%C3%A4.html
```

To me it looks like, the logentry `javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path` shows the wrong enoding aÃ¤.html. The lines with a%C3%A4.html seem to be correctly encoded.

Any idea, what I may have forgotten? Any idea what could help?

Richard

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You need to (let your admin to) set the `URIEncoding` attribute of the `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml` to `UTF-8` as well.</strike>

```
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

<strike>They're otherwise by default interpreted as ISO 8859-1, which is a single-byte character encoding. The individual `0xC3` and `0xA4` bytes of the UTF-8 `ä` character will then indeed be represented as the characters `Ã` and `¤` respectively, see also [the ISO 8859-1 codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout).</strike>

#### <strike>See also:</strike>

- <strike>[Tomcat 5.5 Configuration Reference - The HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)</strike>

---

**Update**: sorry, I overlooked that you've already set the `URIEncoding` attribute. Now that seems to be a Tomcat 5.0 specific issue. Setting that attribute fixes the problem on Tomcat 7 (and most likely also the latest 6). I recommend upgrading to a newer Tomcat version. Tomcat 5.0 is EOL for years.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I did this already. Like I wrote: "The Tomcat-HTTP-Connector ist set to URIEncoding="UTF-8" in my posting.

Comment: Do you know a way to check if the <Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
setting is working? Is there some kind of debug-output where one can read the URIEncoding-setting?

Comment: UPDATE: I checked, that `<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">` is working in the way, that the QUERY-String-Part of the URL is correctly en-/decoded in UTF-8, but the Server/Filename-Part of the URL is not.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked it. Perhaps it's a Tomcat 5.5 specific issue. That `URIEncoding` setting did it for me on Tomcat 7. I changed the answer.